# Target class inside a particular class with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a number of `.job-card-wrap`'s, inside each of those is a class `.arrow`. I want to hover each `.job-card-wrap` and change the `src` of `.arrow`.

This is what I have, however hovering on one `.job-card-wrap` changes the `src`of all `.arrows`

```
$(function(){
    $(".job-card-wrap").on({
      mouseenter: function(){
        $(".arrow").attr('src','./images/arrow-blue.png');
      },
      mouseleave: function(){
        $(".arrow").attr('src','./images/arrow-grey.png');
      }
    });
  });
```

How do I target the specific `.arrow` class when hovering on the current `.job-card-wrap`? I can't really assign IDs as I have no way of telling how many `.job-card-wrap`'s I will get back from a search

Comment: Don't do that. On hover you're making an additional request to the server, meanwhile you users will see a blank image/nothing

Comment: For such purpose you can use entirely CSS `:hover`

Comment: The additional request will be made only the first time, then the image will be cached... And this is true using jQuery **or** a CSS rule.

Comment: My image size is 830 bytes - will there really be such lag to worry about?

Comment: I wouldn't care either... ;)

Comment: Gavin, say I load your page and suddenly I enter a tunnel... or lose my neighbor internet connection for a while...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: lolll.... Don't surf and drive!

Comment: it's a rather common problem that already has a few solutions: preload, image sprites, not using images, etc.. I prefer the 3rd one for this use case. (use fonts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$(this)`, which is the hovered element, and then [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target a child.

```
$(function(){
  $(".job-card-wrap").on({
    mouseenter: function(){
      $(this).find(".arrow").attr('src','./images/arrow-blue.png');
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
      $(this).find(".arrow").attr('src','./images/arrow-grey.png');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `$(this).find(".arrow")`, `this` will mean *the currently hovered .job-card-wrap*

**or instead of JS use CSS:**

```
.job-card-wrap .arrow {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    background-image: url('../images/arrow-blue.png');
}

.job-card-wrap:hover .arrow {
    background-image: url('../images/arrow-grey.png');
}
```

Again, even in CSS it's best to use a preloaded font icon or to create a sprite (both images on a single .png) and than simply move the background using CSS `background-position`

```
.job-card-wrap .arrow {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-image: url('../images/arrow-blue-gray.png'); /* 48x24px image */
}

.job-card-wrap:hover .arrow {
    background-position: -24px 0;
}
```